# Temperature-dependence of circadian rythms

Tags: circadian-rhythms

A [circadian rhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm) is a chemical clock. In the absence of light or other stimuli to entrain it, its speed depends on reaction rates.

As a rule of thumb reaction rates [double every 10C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm) as long as the enzymes don't denature. The "rule of thumb" predicts that a mild 0.5C temperature change would alter the 24 hour cycle by almost an hour/day, which is quite noticeable. Does (non-hazardous) heat/cold exposure advance/delay the circadian rhythm? If so, is it in line with the "rule of thumb"?

Comment: What do you mean by “entrain”? And presumably the verb, whatever it is supposed to mean, has on object. And circadian rhythms are generally referred to as “biological” clocks. In any case, the idea that  the **length** of circadian rhythms are limited by the **rate** (speed) of a chemical reaction or reactions seems to me absurd, given their length. Before twiddling your rules of thumb you need to identify the reactions that you think are limiting in a specific instance.

Comment: this question is fully answered in the wikipedia article.